# Use of \@array doesn't match its definition

Tags: tables, arrays

I am doing something wrong here. I get a message saying

```
Use of \@array doesn't match its definition. `\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def  
\reserved@a { #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... l.108 ...tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{3cm}
|c|c|l|c|}.
```

Here is a complete code

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{textcomp, booktabs}
\begin{document}
\section*{\large \textrecipe}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{3cm}|c|c|l|c|}
\toprule 
Sr No & Drug & Dose  & frequency & Duration & Remark \midrule
1 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \midrule
\hline 
2 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\
\hline 
3 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ 
\hline 
4 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ 
\hline 
5 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night  \\
\hline 
6 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\
\hline 
7 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night  \bottomrule 

\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: you need the `array` package for the extended `.>{...}` syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.
Just add array package
or 
Modify code like this

```
\section*{\large \textrecipe}
\begin{table}[htp]
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{c p{3cm}p{3cm}clc} 
\toprule 
 Sr No & Drug & Dose  & frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \midrule
1 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

 2 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

3 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ 

 4 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ 

5 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night  \\

6 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

7 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ \bottomrule 

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be an idea not to use `[h]` but at least `[htp]`. If the table is a bit long, it will not fit at as a `[h]=[ht]` float. And since the list is then empty, the float ends up at the end of the chapter.

Comment: It's a bad idea mixing commands from `booktabs` like `\toprule` and `\midrule` with vertical rules. Just remove the `|` characters in the argument to `tabular` and the useless `\hline` you have.